# How to center text in html?

Tags: html, css, center

In short, I tried to center one `<div>` with `text-align: center;` for `display: inline-block;`, but nothing seems to happen. I tried to center it with `justify-content: center; align-items: center;` for `display: inline-flex;`, and again, nothing seems to happen. The only way to center them is I added `text-align: center;` to the `<body>`, but that will make the whole document center, while I want only that one `<div>` to be centered and the rest not centered.

Here is my code:

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./reset.css">
    </head>
    <style>

    body {
        color: blue;
        background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
        /*text-align: center;*/
    }

    .head2 {
        font-size:20px;
        color: red;
        background-color: cyan;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /*.head1 {
        font-size:20px;
        color: red;
        background-color: cyan;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }*/

    </style>
        <body>
            <p>some text</p>
            <div class="head1">
                <p class="head2">Some another text</P>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I want to center only the cyan box.
I'll be really thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `text-align:center` in `.head1`

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./reset.css">
    </head>
    <style>

    body {
        color: blue;
        background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
        /*text-align: center;*/
    }

    .head2 {
        font-size:20px;
        color: red;
        background-color: cyan;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    /*.head1 {
        font-size:20px;
        color: red;
        background-color: cyan;
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
    }*/
    
    .head1 {
       text-align:center;
    }

    </style>
        <body>
            <p>some text</p>
            <div class="head1">
                <p class="head2">Some another text</P>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<style>
body {
    color: blue;
    background-color: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    /*text-align: center;*/
}

.head2 {
    font-size:20px;
    color: red;
    background-color: cyan;
    text-align: center;
}

/*.head1 {
    font-size:20px;
    color: red;
    background-color: cyan;
    display: inline-block;
 
}*/

</style>
    <body>
        <p>some text</p>
        <div class="head1">
            <p class="head2">Some another text</P>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```